# ID # being reset in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

In my controller action I am attempting to retrieve a record from the DB:

```
            Dim surveyDB = db.Surveys.Find(sid)
```

Where *sid* is instantiated at the Class level:

```
    Private sid As New Integer
```

When I first create a new Survey (If surveyDB Is Nothing), I add it to the DB and set *sid* like so:

```
                db.Surveys.Add(survey)
                Await db.SaveChangesAsync()
                sid = survey.SurveyID
```

That seems to go just fine (say the new survey goes into row 20 so survey.SurveyID = 20), except that if I go back to that page, *sid* is getting reset for some reason, so surveyDB is always Nothing.

Why in ASP.NET would a Class-level variable be getting reset?  How do I get it to properly find the record I'm looking for?

Comment: If you need the code to execute synchronously - just don't just the await, and it will run in that fashion.

Comment: Apparently when you do not use "Await" you have to call the non-Async function, which in this case is "db.Surveys.Find(sid)".  I did not know before that there is a .Find.  That said, I guess I have a different issue, because even when I do have a record that should be getting found, sid (the ID #) keeps getting reset to 0.  I will update my question with this info.

Answer (score 0):

> The code after that is an IF that depends on the result from the above line:

This should actually be automatic (as far as I am aware) when you have an await, when a expression attempts to use the value it should suspend until the await finishes.  This is really important to figure out before you attempt a solution like the one below.

Otherwise....

One option is to wait for it to complete (or any number of them to complete):

```
Dim surveyDB = db.Surveys.FindAsync(sid)

Task.WhenAll(surveyDB)

If IsNothing(surveyDB.Result) Then
  //...
Else
  //...
End If
```

This would allow you to add any number of async calls:

```
Dim surveyDB = db.Surveys.FindAsync(sid)
Dim surveyDB1 = db.Surveys.FindAsync(sid1)
Dim surveyDB2 = db.Surveys.FindAsync(sid2)

Task.WhenAll(surveyDB, surveyDB1, survyeDB2)

If IsNothing(surveyDB.Result) Then
  //...
Else
  //...
End If
```

Comment: The line "Task.WhenAll(surveyDB)" gives me an error.

Comment: Instead of `gives me an error` it's much more useful to state something like `I get the Exception - InvalidOperationException with the message "Whatever the Exception Message states"`.  Just stating you get an error is impossible for anyone to diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by using a Session variable instead of a Class variable and checking the value of that first, updating the row using Entity State if it's not already there:

```
            If Session("sid") Is Nothing Then
                db.Surveys.Add(survey)
                Await db.SaveChangesAsync()
                Session("sid") = survey.SurveyID
            Else
                db.Entry(survey).State = EntityState.Modified
                Await db.SaveChangesAsync()
            End If
```